# Best alternative for the Top Clause in Sql Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-order-by, clause

i am working on a table which currently contains 100000 records, and will be more and more in future, now my clients want the LATEST TOP 10 RECORDS...

using top clause diminishes the performance, and as this is the mobile application, performance is the only concern, so is there any alternate and the best way for getting Latest Top 10 records also the order by could result in loss of performance

does these two have any best performance alternative..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the best option is use another table where you have the latest 10 records.

So, when your app insert a record, it has to record it in both tables... The big one and the top 10 one. Or it is possible to do a trigger that do this work.

Comment: +1 This is the most performant solution if @Abbas doesn't mind the trigger overhead or denormalizing the data.

Comment: @Gabotron: let me check whether i got you properly, you mean to create a new table say topArticle, which will default have top 10 articles, now when user add's new article, then it will be added to the default article table and also in topArticle table and will remove the last record, so that the top 10 records are maintained.. is this what you meant, and can you tell me what you meant by "The big one and the Top 10 one."

Comment: Yeap Abbas... But BradC has the right point... Do you have a proper Index?

Comment: +1; If you haven't set an index on the value(s) you're querying on, then that's the first step.  After that I'd say go with this answer.  Also, not sure if it would help (don't know all the details) but you could look into using an indexed view instead of manually creating another table: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc917715.aspx

Answer (score 6):

Using the TOP clause hurts performance only because you don't have the proper index on the date field (or whatever field you are using to identify the 10 latest). For a query like:

```
SELECT TOP 10 OrderID, OrderDate, TotalPrice, Shipping, Status
FROM CustomerOrder
ORDER By OrderDate DESC
```

You'll need (ideally) an index on:

```
(OrderDate, OrderID) INCLUDE (TotalPrice, Shipping, Status)
```

Comment: +1 This is also *likely* correct. Given a proper index MSSQL should be able to retrieve the data promptly, regardless of the number of rows.